# meteor-client-bundler with webpack __meteor_runtime_config__ is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, webpack

I am trying to use this with my webpack project

https://blog.meteor.com/leverage-the-power-of-meteor-with-any-client-side-framework-bfb909141008

but I get this error

`ReferenceError: __meteor_runtime_config__ is not defined`

Here are the steps I did

create a new meteor project

then I run the client bundler like this

`meteor-client bundle —source=./ —destination=./meteor-client.bundle.js —config=meteor-client.config.json`

and here is the config

```
{
  "runtime": {
    "DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL": "http://localhost:3000"
  },
  "import": [
    "meteor-base@1.3.0",
    "mongo@1.4.2",
    "reactive-var@1.0.11",
    "jquery@1.11.10",
    "tracker@1.1.3",
    "shell-server@0.3.1",
    "react-meteor-data"
  ]
}
```

then I copy my `meteor-client.js` to my webpack project `node_modules`

and import it like this

`import 'meteor-client'`

then I bundle webpack and run dev-server and I get the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and fixed that by putting my `meteor-client.js` to node_modules and exclude node_modules from processing by babel-loader with webpack (or you could just exclude meteor-client.js). Raw loading will workaround that.
In case someone still searching.